# Can I use xsdata python library (or a better option that you know) to serialize a python data object(using dataclass) to an xml output using a xsd?

Tags: python, xml-serialization, python-dataclasses

I have a complex data structure (with nested classes and all) in my python code, accurately implemented using dataclasses.
Now I need to serialize an instance of the dataclass with data into an xml file using an existing xsd schema definition.
How can I do that?
I found xsdata which seems like it should have the capability but I couldn't find how to do it.

```
@dataclass
class Address:
    address1 : object = field(default=None)
    address2 : object = field(default=None)
    city : object = field(default=None)
    state : object = field(default=None)
    pin_code : object = field(default=None)
    country : object = field(default=None)
    
@dataclass
class OrderAddress:
    address_name : object = field(default=None)
    address_phone : object = field(default=None)
    address_details : Address=field(default=None)
```

Here is a part of the corresponding xsd

```
<xs:complexType name="AddressType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Contains Customer information such as Name, Physical Postal Address, and Contact Information.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Name" default="Customer" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>(Optional) Name is the full name of the Customer.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="150"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="CustomerAddress1" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>(Optional) CustomerAddress1 is the Address Line 1 of the Customer.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="250"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="CustomerAddress2" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>(Optional) CustomerAddress2 is the Address Line 2 of the Customer.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="250"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="CustomerAddress3" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>(Optional) CustomerAddress3 is the Address Line 3 of the Customer.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="250"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="City" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>(Optional) City is the Customer's City location.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="State" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>(Optional) State is the Customer's State location.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Zip" default="00000" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>(Optional) Zip is the Customer's Zipcode location. If there is no Zipcode provided, if the field is an empty-tag, or if there is no-tag - the System will default to five zero-digits only for billing address.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Country" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>(Optional) Country is the Customer's Country location.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Phone" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>(Optional) Phone is the Customer's Phone Number.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

I want to be able to output this xml from an OrderAddress object populated with data as shown below:

```
    <BillingAddress>
      <Name>Name1</Name>
      <Address1>Address11</Address1>
      <Address2>Address21</Address2>
      <Address3>Address31</Address3>
      <City>City1</City>
      <State>State1</State>
      <Zip>Zip1</Zip>
      <Country>Country1</Country>
      <Email>Email1</Email>
      <Phone>Phone1</Phone>
    </BillingAddress>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an xml schema you can use xsdata's code generator to create the models for you.

See [here](https://xsdata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/codegen.html#generate-code)

```
❯ xsdata generate schema.xsd
Parsing schema schema.xsd
Compiling schema schema.xsd
Builder: 1 main and 0 inner classes
Analyzer input: 1 main and 0 inner classes
Analyzer output: 1 main and 0 inner classes
Generating package: init
Generating package: generated.schema
```